# Mudar style no ng-click e após um tempo retornar ao normal com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte problema: preciso que um campo seja mostrado em uma solução com uma "máscara" como se o mesmo estivesse oculto. Quando ocorrer um evento ou um click em um botão (ou em si mesmo) tal campo seja preenchido com um valor e após um tempo o mesmo volte a ser mostrado com sua "máscara". Assim:

**No HTML**

```
<div ng-click="mudaCampo()">
    {{campo}}
</div>
```

**No JS**

```
$scope.campo = '*****';

$scope.valorCampo = 'ola mundo';

$scope.mudaCampo = function(){

    //mostro o valor real do campo, existente em outra variável
    $scope.campo = $scope.valorCampo;

    //volta o valor mostrado no html para a "mascara" anterior
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.campo = '*****'; 
    },2000);

};
```

Meu problema é que `$scope.campo` até muda para o valor de `$scope.valorCampo` mas a função `setTimeout` não retorna o valor do mesmo para a máscara anterior... help?

**Nota**
Eu até procurei ver como funciona o `$timeout` mas quando tento usar o mesmo o Angular acusa um erro sobre a falta do evento...

Comment: O mais provável e faltar o `$scope.$apply()` para que o valor do campo seja mudado. Experimente usar `[$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) em vez do `setTimeout` dado que o primeiro, por *default* chama o `$scope.$apply` (veja a documentação)

Answer (score 2):

Como informado pelo @Omni, fui atrás do `$timeout` e percebi que estava utilizando o mesmo de forma incorreta. Pra ser sincero também não conhecia o `$scope.$apply` que aplica as mudanças existentes no meu controller... basicamente ficou assim:

**No JS**

```
$scope.campo = '*****';

$scope.valorCampo = 'ola mundo';

$scope.mudaCampo = function(){

    //mostro o valor real do campo, existente em outra variável
    $scope.campo = $scope.valorCampo;

    //volta o valor mostrado no html para a "mascara" anterior
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.campo = '*****';
    },1000);

};
```

Lembrando que, é necessário declarar o `$timeout` como uma dependência do meu controller senão ele não funciona.